# Is it grammatical to say "what good is a doctor if he can't even save his patient"

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> What good is a doctor if he can't even save his patient?

The meaning I am trying to express here is that the doctor is not a good one if he cannot save his patient.

Comment: Apart from it being a question, it's fine grammatically.  What is the cause of your concern?

Comment: As a general note, many excellent doctors are unable to save the lives of some patients. One thing does not necessarily equate with the other. Also, I would say *save the* ***life of*** *his patient*. But the sentence is grammatical as it was given—aside from a missing question mark.

Comment: Women can be doctors too!

Comment: My concern was more about the first part of the sentence, I was unsure if "what good is" is the right thing here (was thinking other phrases like "how good is" or "what good of"). And also let me clarify, I am not blaming any doctor (or intentionally leaving out he/she)! Just studying this English sentence! (this note was in the question but was then edited out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your sentence is grammatically correct. Proceed!